# Overloading operator* for a matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I have a matrix:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

class Matrix
{   
    public:
        Matrix(int rows, int columns);
        Matrix(int, int, int** matrix); 
        Matrix(Matrix* copy);
        ~Matrix();

        void Set(int, int, int);
        void SetMatrix(int, int, int** matrix);             
        void Print();
        void ZeroMatrix(int,int,int** matrix);      
        void Add(Matrix* B);
        void Subtract(Matrix* B);
        void Copy(Matrix* B);

        int** Multiply(Matrix* B);
        int** Create(int,int);
        int** Get();
        int** Transpose();
        int** Scalar(int);

        int Get(int,int);
        int Rows();
        int Columns();

        Matrix operator*(int);

    private:
        int** _matrix;
        int _rows;
        int _columns;
};

#endif
```

Here's the implementation:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator*(int scale)
{
    return Matrix(_rows, _columns, Scalar(scale));
}
```

And for a school assignment we have to overload the multiple operator to work with integer scalar. The problem is I keep getting this error:

main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:18:15: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘4 * B’

Breaking code:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    Matrix* A = new Matrix(4,2);

    A->Set(0,0,1);  
    A->Set(0,1,2);
    A->Set(1,0,3);
    A->Set(1,1,4);  
    A->Print();

    Matrix B(A);
    B.Print();

    Matrix C(4 * B); //this line
    C.Print();


    delete A;

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

edit # 1:

the code:

```
Matrix operator*(int); 
        Matrix operator* (int, const Matrix &);
```

generates:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
Matrix.h:31:40: error: ‘Matrix Matrix::operator*(int, const Matrix&)’ must take either zero or one argument
In file included from matrix.cpp:1:0:
Matrix.h:31:40: error: ‘Matrix Matrix::operator*(int, const Matrix&)’ must take either zero or one argument
matrix.cpp:207:50: error: ‘Matrix Matrix::operator*(int, const Matrix&)’ must take either zero or one argument
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need either `fstream` or `iostream` in the main file, as nothing from either is actually used in main. Best to just include what you need on a per-file basis.

Comment: homework should have the homework tag

Comment: @chris: it was for something i was testing earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify your member function, your class must be the left hand side.

`B * 4` is equivalent to `B.operator* (4)`. When you say `4 * B`, this does not work.

To remedy this, simply use `B * 4` instead of `4 * B`, or provide an external overload

```
Matrix operator* (int, const Matrix &);
```

Then, the `4 * B` will match this overload.

Comment: you're doing `Matrix Matrix::operator*`, while you should (as posted above) do `Matrix operator*` (thus, define it outside the class (or externally, in chris's words))

Comment: @Jasper, thanks, I was wondering what was going wrong. I made my own little test and it worked perfectly. @StormKiernan, remember `B * 4` is compatible with what you have right now :/

Comment: @StormKiernan, I'm not sure if you did this, but you need to define a body for that `Matrix operator* (int, const Matrix &)`. Use the same body as your other operator overload. If you need access to private members, declare it as a friend in your class. The one above it, with just an int is pointless.

Comment: In addition to these suggestions, you can define a function outside of the class that overloads the '*' operator and have it take as parameters two Matrix objects. Make this function a friend of the class and then use a convert constructor to handle passing as an argument in either the first or second paramenter. If you want an example, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This will work in either direction...

```
#include <iostream>

class Matrix
{
public:
  Matrix(int x) // This works as a convert constructor
    : _x(x) { } // if you don't use the explicit keyword

  friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix& left, const Matrix& right);

  int _x;
};

Matrix operator*(const Matrix& left, const Matrix& right)
{
  return Matrix(left._x * right._x);
}

int main()
{
  Matrix m(3);
  int a = 4;

  Matrix m1(m * a);
  Matrix m2(a * m);

  std::cout << m._x  << endl  // 3
            << a     << endl  // 4
            << m1._x << endl  // 12
            << m2._x << endl; // 12
}
```